# How to increase Thai curry flavour without increase spicy

Tags: thai-cuisine

I'm using this Curry paste but my girlfriend doest like too spicy, therefore the flavor is really bland.. how can increase the flavor without make it too spicy?

[image: Curry paste]

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/30398/67

Answer (score 5):

I did a search for Gelbe Curry Paste and found the product in your pic in a result from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003W5LFMC).

Based on what I read in a review, you add coconut milk to this curry paste. Therefore I'm hopefully correct that you are toning down the heat and flavors by adding more coconut milk or other milk. So after you tone it down, you want to add flavor back but not add more heat.

The product description lists the ingredients as:

> Product of Thailand Dried Red Chili, Shallot, Garlic, Lemongrass, Salt, Galangal, Tumeric, Cumin, Coriander Seeds, Spices

You can add flavor back by adding some of the listed ingredients (to your liking), but not adding more chili. In the US ingredients are listed in order of amount, highest to lowest. While this may or may not be the case here, it may help with deciding which to add more of.

You'll likely have to play around a bit, but hopefully you can get that flavor back.

Answer (score 4):

- Buy a mild version if you can
- Add salt to enhance the flavors, so long as it doesn't end up tasting salty
- Add milk or milk powder to the curry, though that'll change the flavor (Milk is known to counter spiciness)
- I guess you can try messing around with adding sweetness or acid to somewhat attempt to counter the spiciness, but it won't really help that much
- Have your gf eat more spicy food so that she gains a tolerance to it

Comment: I would go for coconut milk over regular milk ... but the finding a less spicy curry paste will go a *long* way.  (when I cooked for my neighbors, we'd make it mild, and the two of us who preferred it hotter would just add to it)

Comment: salt is not a substitute for flavor, that's so.. fast food

Comment: @GeorgeM It's not substitute for flavor, it's making the already existing flavor stronger so that less curry paste is needed. Now, since salt inhibits bitter and amplifies other senses, it might very mildly mess up the company's intended flavor, but it doesn't appear that bitter is an important aspect of this flavor profile so salt should work just fine. The goal of any cook it to saturate the salt so that you extract the most amount of flavor without hitting the point at which you can actually taste the salt itself.

Comment: When fast food fries just taste like salt because they can't actually get a good spice mix, then you're using the flavor of the salt to substitute for actual flavor, as opposed to simply using the chemistry of sodium to flavor enhance (Since there's nothing to enhance anyway, other than the potato).

Answer (score 3):

why not try making your own curry paste? I usually use curry paste from cans but once i tried few recipes, I never looked back.
I like [this one](https://www.cookclickndevour.com/thai-green-curry-recipe-vegetarian-thai-green-curry-recipe/) particularly

Also you can just add crushed ginger garlic while adding the sote ought curry paste

Comment: I think that's the best way! You can even freeze the paste if you want, in ice cube trays, so the first time is going to be a lot more work, but the next times, it'll be as easy as buying paste from the store ! Then you can add a lot of tasty spices but not a lot of chili, so it will still be tasty but not "spicy".